# 2 Possible Package Resolutions

Tags: python, package, spyder, qtconsole

I can't connect to kernel in Spyder 4, and when I try to update qtconsole, I get the following error:

```
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - defaults::jupyter_console-6.0.0-py37_0, defaults::prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py_0
  - defaults::jupyter_console-5.2.0-py37_1, defaults::prompt_toolkit-3.0.2-pydone
```

I have tried updating Anaconda, and uninstalling qtconsole, but for some reason 5.2.0 won't go away. I tried using pip as well, but that didn't work either as it says there is no package called qtconsole. Anyone know how to get rid of 5.2.0?

FIX: I just entered `conda uninstall jupyter_console` and that fixed it.

Comment: Glad to know you were able to fix this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Me too have faced the same problem:

```
conda update --all

...

Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - defaults::jupyter_console-6.0.0-py36_0, defaults::prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py_0
  - defaults::jupyter_console-5.2.0-py36_1, defaults::prompt_toolkit-3.0.2-pydone
```

Then I (may have) solved it with :

```
conda update prompt_toolkit
```

`jupyter_console` was downgraded to 5.2 though.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem when I tried to update the spyder. It showed this warning:

> Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
>     - defaults::jupyter_console-6.0.0-py36_0, defaults::prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py_0
>     - defaults::jupyter_console-5.2.0-py36_1, defaults::prompt_toolkit-3.0.2-pydone

I have tried: `conda uninstall jupyter_console` but it didn't work. Are there other methods?